# Dart check list is equal map key show map value

Tags: flutter, dart

hey I have like that List

```
List<String> list = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

and ı have like that map

```
Map<String, String> map = {'Hello': 'a', 'How': 'b', 'You': 'c'};
```

I want make function like that if is a i want return Hello how can i do it can you help me ?

```
find(a) {
 //return Hello
}
```

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're asking, but if you want to be able to look up `Map` entries by value instead of by key, perhaps try [`Map.invert`](https://pub.dev/documentation/basics/latest/map_basics/MapBasics/invert.html) from [`package:basics`](https://pub.dev/packages/basics) or [`BiMap`](https://pub.dev/documentation/quiver/latest/quiver.collection/BiMap-class.html) from [`package:quiver`](https://pub.dev/packages/quiver).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understand you correctly.

Try this, you retrieve the key using the value

```
Map<String, String> map = {'Hello': 'a', 'How': 'b', 'You': 'c'};

// search for 'b' value 
var data = map.keys.firstWhere((k) => map[k] == 'b', orElse: () => null);

print(data); // prints 'How'
```